# Error with Excel Macro for Dynamic array filtering

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter

I have this line that works perfectly

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A6").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("13.1", "13.2", "13.3", "13.4", "13.5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

The problem is that this is not dynamic, I tried numerous ways to make this dynamic but all failed
I want to these values to be taken from activesheet cells Q1,R1,S1,T1,U1,V1.

but any method I use it will filter only the first two but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can (directly) extract an array to be used as Criteria. But the array elements **must be strings**, even if the filtered column contains numbers... In order  to make it working, each array element must be converted to string.

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testFilteringCol5()
  Dim arrCrit() As Variant, i As Long
  
  arrCrit = Range("Q1:V1").value 'place the range in an array

  'cast each array element to string:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrCrit, 2): arrCrit(1, i) = CStr(arrCrit(1, i)): Next i
  
  'use the strings array as `Criteria1` (columns headers must exist on the 6th row):
  ActiveSheet.Range("A6").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=arrCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Note that the filter will fail if number format of the range is set and the result of `CStr` is different form the displayed number. Example: Q1 contains the value `13.1`. `CStr(Q1)`  will return the string `"13.1"`, (no matter how Q1 it is formatted.  If now the data cells (column F) are formattet to show 2 digits (`13.10`), the filter will fail.

Comment: @FaneDuru wow, that worked 100% correctly, I gave up and thought it was impossible, even chatgpt couldn't do it after giving me 10-15 macros to try